# Laravel - Pivot table - No join throws an error

Tags: laravel, pivot

I've a question regarding how Laravel handles pivot tables:

Summarizing: 2 models, Project and Stage.

Project

```
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Project1 |
|  2 | Project2 |
+----+----------+
```

Stage

```
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Stage1 |
|  2 | Stage2 |
|  3 | Stage3 |
+----+--------+
```

And a pivot table

```
+----+------------+----------+------------+-----------+
| id | project_id | stage_id |    date    |   info    |
+----+------------+----------+------------+-----------+
|  1 |          1 |        1 | 2014-12-20 | Moreinfo1 |
|  2 |          1 |        2 | 2014-12-21 | Moreinfo2 |
|  3 |          2 |        1 | 2014-12-22 | Moreinfo3 |
|  4 |          1 |        3 | 2014-12-23 | Moreinfo4 |
+----+------------+----------+------------+-----------+
```

I'm showing the info:

```
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
| project  | last_stage |    date    |   info    |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
| Project1 |          3 | 2014-12-23 | Moreinfo4 |
| Project2 |          1 | 2014-12-22 | Moreinfo3 |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

And everything works fine; however, if I add a new Project (as there's no info on the pivot table), I get the annoying:

**Whoops, looks like something went wrong.**

Is there any way to indicate that, in case of null, the row should be left empty (without an error)? I'd like to get:

```
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
| project  | last_stage |    date    |   info    |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
| Project1 |          3 | 2014-12-23 | Moreinfo4 |
| Project2 |          1 | 2014-12-22 | Moreinfo3 |
| Project3 |            |            |           |
+----------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Can you either enable debugging in `app/config/app.php` or look at `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` and post the real error message here?

Comment: Sure, this is the output of debugging: Trying to get property of non-object (View: /home/pete/project/app/views/projects.blade.php).  This is the line in the view where I want to retrieve the info: <td>{{$project->stages_accomp()->orderBy('date', 'desc')->first()->pivot->date}}</td>  and stages_accomp @ Project: return $this->belongsToMany('Stage')->withPivot('date', 'info'); [Tried to break into different lines... with little success]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the call in your view:

```
{{ $project->stages_accomp()->orderBy('date', 'desc')->first()->pivot->date }}
```

When you have a project that has no `stage` assigned `->first()` will return `null`.

And PHP doesn't like it if you want to access a property of a non-object (in this case `null`)

You need to add a little check like this:

```
@if($stage = $project->stages_accomp()->orderBy('date', 'desc')->first())
    {{ $stage->pivot->date }}
@endif
```

It will make sure the `first()` returns a truthy value (not `null`) and will also assign the value to the variable `$stage`.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. Didn't know if Eloquent would take care of it automatically, but it sounds logical to thrown an exception in case of null.